# How to put the navbar in the foreground and the divs in the background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a custom home page for my PC web browsers but when I scroll, the navbar is behind the divs. I'd be grateful to test a few solutions :D

Note: The icons and the weather, clock and calendar scripts are in separate files so it'll be broken for you but it's not what I need to fix so don't worry if these things are missing/broken.

[image: Normal position]

[image: When scrolling]

I was expecting the divs to go behind the navbar but the divs are showing in the foreground...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
        <title>Accueil Perso</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="./resources/favicons/home.ico">
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/product-sans');
        </style>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="calendar"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/calendrier.png"><span id="date"></span></li>
                <script src="calendar.js"></script>
                <li class="clock"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/montre.png"><span id="time"></span></li>
                <script src="clock.js"></script>
                <li class="weather">
                    <img alt="" src="./resources/icons/soleil.png">
                    <span id="description"></span>
                    <span id="temp"></span>
                    <span id="location"></span>
                </li>
                <script src="weather.js"></script>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>
            <h1><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript for this page to be able to work properly.</noscript></h1>
            <div class="CommunicationBox">
                <h1>Communication</h1>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://discord.com/channels/@me"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/discord.png">Discord</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?hl=fr#inbox"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/gmail.png">Gmail</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.messenger.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/messenger.png">Messenger</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://teams.live.com/_#/conversations/?ctx=chat"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/microsoft-teams.png">Microsoft Teams</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/outlook.png">Outlook</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://mail.proton.me/u/0/inbox"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/protonmail.png">Proton Mail</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://web.skype.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/skype.png">Skype</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://web.snapchat.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/snapchat.png">Snapchat</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://web.telegram.org/z"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/telegram.png">Telegram</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://web.whatsapp.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/whatsapp.png">WhatsApp</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="SocialNetworksBox">
                <h1>Réseaux Sociaux</h1>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/facebook.png">Facebook</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/instagram.png">Instagram</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.reddit.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/reddit.png">Reddit</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://stackoverflow.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/stack-overflow.png">Stack Overflow</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tiktok.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/tiktok.png">TikTok</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.twitch.tv"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/twitch.png">Twitch</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/twitter.png">Twitter</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.youtube.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/youtube.png">YouTube</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://studio.youtube.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/youtube-studio.png">YouTube Studio</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ShoppingBox">
                <h1>Shopping</h1>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://fr.aliexpress.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/aliexpress.ico">AliExpress</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://amazon.fr"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/amazon.png">Amazon</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cdiscount.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/cdiscount.ico">Cdiscount</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.ebay.fr"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/aide.png">eBay</a></p>
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://fr.ifixit.com"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/ifixit.png">iFixit</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.leboncoin.fr"><img alt="" src="./resources/icons/leboncoin.png">leboncoin</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
```

CSS file that gives a nice look to the page

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://bing.biturl.top/?resolution=1920&format=image&index=0&mkt=fr-FR);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
}

main img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Product Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul img {
    vertical-align: -8%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

li {
    font-family: 'Product Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Product Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.calendar {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clock {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.weather {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}

.CommunicationBox {
    border: 2px outset rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-indent: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.SocialNetworksBox {
    border: 2px outset rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-indent: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ShoppingBox {
    border: 2px outset rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-indent: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

div h1 {
    color: white;
}

a img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

p a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add z-index: 10 property in Unordered List(ul) it will work.

ul {
z-index: 10
}

Comment: my measure, it worked for you. :)